# How to add wikipage in wikipage library using powershell?

Tags: 2013, powershell, document-library, publishing-page, wiki-pages

I tried to add a wikipage in the wikipage library using the code provided by *Vijai Anand Ramalingam* on [c-sharpcorner.com](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-add-wiki-page-to-the-wiki-page-library-in-sharepoint-using-powershell1).

I'm copy-pasting the script here to avoid dead link issues preventing future readers from accessing it. I obviously replaced all the variables to allow the script to suits my local environnement.

```
$listName="A"
$siteURL="http://serverName:1111"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$list=$web.Lists[$listName]               
$rootFolder = $list.RootFolder
$wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add("/"+$rootFolder+"/Home.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
$wikiItem = $wikiPage.Item
$wikiItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId]::WikiField] = "Template Preview" 
$wikiItem.UpdateOverwriteVersion()
```

This code is not working because it throws the following error:

*You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression*

*$wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add("/"+$rootFolder+"/Home7.aspx", [Microsoft.Sh ...*

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add("/"+$rootFolder+"/Home.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
```

by

```
$wikiPage = $rootFolder.Files.Add($rootFoler.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Home.aspx", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTemplateFileType]::WikiPage)
```